# Multilingual website in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multilingual

I'm searching for a way to translate a complete website (Homepage, about us, product pages, contact, FAQ, ..) in multiple languages. The website is build in ReactJS with Firebase Database.

All the examples I found are just small translations like a greeting or How are you but what with complete websites? Is my best option making an JS object for each language and work with hundred of maybe thousand template strings? (That should definitely end up with tags like 'homepageContactSectionSubDiscription' or 'homepageProductSectionFeaturesItemTwo')

Comment: you should use  https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Comment: Did you not look into this? i8ln react or react localization brings back tons of resources.

Comment: I personally use https://www.i18next.com directly and it has been a pleasure...

Answer (score 9):

You should look into using `react-intl`. [Github](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)

You can specify various language files:

en.json

```
{
    "greeting": "Hello"
}
```

es.json

```
{
    "greeting": "Hola"
}
```

And then use them within your components using `FormattedMessage`:

```
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
...
<FormattedMessage id="greeting" />
```

React intl provides a wrapper for your application to allow specifying different languages and their associated messages.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <IntlProvider locale="en">
        <App />
    </IntlProvider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

An important note, this will not perform translations for you, but provide you with a method of pulling from different language files based on the specified `locale`.

If you find yourself having a very large language file, you can split it up into different sections. For example, I may have two files, `home.json` and `settings.json`, which I can set up to access as `home.{unique_id}` or `settings.{another_unique_id}`

Comment: Yes but that's again an example with just a simple greeting. I'm talking about hundred of elements. Do I have to give every element an unique id like 'homepageProductSectionFeaturesItemTwo'?

Comment: @Thore yes, there is no service that will provide translations for you, although it's possible you could pay for translations to be generated. I tend to break up my language files by pages/components, similar to what you would do in React, with a separate file for common words/phrases that will be used many times.

Comment: @Thore Additionally, each element should have a unique id.

Comment: @Wolfie you mean that for each element I have add manually ? I have a English language file with 1000 of elements & now my client need to support site in arabic language. So do I need to update the arabic language file by putting element value in arabic language manually. It is very tough to update. Please confirm.

Comment: @NishantPandya yes exactly. You might be able to find a service to do this process for you, but otherwise it will need to be done manually.